# Changing ServerName for MAMP

Tags: apache, mamp, slim

I'm trying to change the ServerName property for my MAMP instance but it doesn't seem to be responding to anything I do.

I edited part of the httpd.conf file (/Applications/MAMP/conf/apache/httpd.conf) to this:

```
#
# ServerName gives the name and port that the server uses to identify itself.
# This can often be determined automatically, but we recommend you specify
# it explicitly to prevent problems during startup.
#
# If your host doesn't have a registered DNS name, enter its IP address here.
#
#ServerName localhost:8888
ServerName slimproject.dev
```

After this I've stopped and started my server.

Yet it is still responding to http://localhost:8888 
When I go to http://slimproject.dev it will tell me "Server Not Found"

Comment: What is the output of `grep ^Listen /Applications/MAMP/conf/apache/httpd.conf` and `host slimproject.dev | grep address`

Comment: First command: Listen 8888 --- Second command: slimproject.dev has address 127.0.53.53

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want your apache to respond to http://slimproject.dev/, you need to:

1. Make your apache listen on port 80 (since that is the default http port), and you can do it by editing `Listen` directive in `httpd.conf` (so replace `Listen 8888` with `Listen 80`.
2. Your browser needs to know that host with the name `slimproject.dev` is actually on your local machine. You can do that for example by issuing this command `echo 127.0.0.1 slimproject.dev >> /etc/hosts`

Additional steps may be needed depending on httpd config, but let's do this first.

(You will probably need `root` access for both above steps)